# Jquery not working to update text in a column

Tags: jquery

Below is my structure.

```
<table class="mrQuestionTable"><tr><td id="Cell.0.0"/></tr></table>
```

I am using below code to insert text in first column but it doesn't work. Ideally, it should be.

```
$('#Cell.0.0').html('Header');
```

Comment: Seems like an invalid selector, why would an element have the class `0`, and why would it have it twice

Comment: Hi Adeneo, Thanks for replying. But when i use below code it works.                                            
 $('.mrQuestionTable td:first').html('Header');

Comment: After adding the HTML, it's clear that you're not selecting classes, but ID's with "invalid" characters

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery to select an ID with a period you need to double escape it:

```
$('#Cell\\.0\\.0').html('Header');
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

Comment: Hmmmm, Thanks, it's working.. I will make a note of this.

Comment: To the anonymous coward that downvoted this, please explain how this is incorrect or not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/03knkL16/

```js
$('td[id="Cell.0.0"]').html('Header');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mrQuestionTable"><tr><td id="Cell.0.0"/></tr></table>
```

Rather than specifying only the `id` use element with attribute as `id` match.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yeah, this is also working. Thanks for all the solution guys!!